# Joomla script issue

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am a beginner of joomla platform. I want to move the mootools.js and caption.js from header to footer. Is it possible to do? Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link to make it `http://www.pbwebdev.com.au/blog/removing-mootools-core-js-caption-js-joomla` cut the code `JHtml::_('behavior.caption');` and paste it in the footer..or you can directly remove them from head by commenting `

```
if ($debug || $konkcheck) {
            JHTML::script('mootools-uncompressed.js', 'media/system/js/', false);
        } else {
            //JHTML::script('mootools.js', 'media/system/js/', false);
        }
        $loaded = true;
        return;
    }

        function caption() {
        //JHTML::script('caption.js');
    }
`in behavior.php from the following path. **libraries\joomla\html\html**
```

Comment: I have cut the code. How can i paste in footer. If any PHP tag need? Because I am not a programmer.

Comment: <?php
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript( '/media/system/js/caption.js' ); $document->addScript( '/media/system/js/mootools.js' );
?>